# Alert Dialog Shortcut

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I use this code in order to make an OK/Cancel dialog box:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            b.setTitle("Login Unsuccessful");
            b.setMessage("Login has failed! Try again!");
            b.setCancelable(false);
            b.setPositiveButton("OK", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    nameTextView.setText("");
                    passTextView.setText("");
                }
            });
            b.create().show();
```

Is this correct? I feel as though it isn't exactly efficient typing out 5 extra lines just to get this damn dialog box to show up. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is it bad to ask questions?

Comment: I didn't downvote but one possibility is that it is a little unclear *exactly what* you are asking.

Comment: I was asking whether there was a shorter way of displaying alert dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I use:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Authentication Error!");
alertDialogBuilder
    .setMessage("User Name/Password is invalid.")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setNeutralButton("Try Again",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
            }
    });

AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

See, if that shorten up your code.